# Why MySQL fetches record even if it doesn't match the ID?

Tags: php, mysql

I just discovered this, I use MySQL as my database.

When i do something like:

```
$query = $this->db->where('id', '6rubbish')->get('posts', 1);
```

it generates and executes this SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`posts`)
WHERE `id` =  '6rubbish'
LIMIT 1
```

The surprising thing is that it actually fetches the post with the ID **6**.

I find this very vulnerable in same cases because i'm trying to exactly match the ID, not to do a LIKE query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

- Read [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html)
- Use [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)() PHP function to extract the integer part of the variable
- Or use [is_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) to exclude any variable that is not a pure integer

But the origin of the problem is that your query generator library doesn't understand the variable types, PHP being a dynamic typed language doesn't help too.

I don't know what library you're using, maybe there is an option to tell that you're passing an int? It should protect you from SQL injection, I hope, try with:

```
$query = $this->db->where('id', "don't")->get('posts', 1);
```

and see if the generated SQL has the single quoted escaped (doubled or preceded by backslash).

Answer (score 0):

That is because `SELECT 6 = '6rubbish'` will give you true, and your id is number type.

Answer (score 0):

Your `id` field is, no doubt, a numeric data type.

When MySQL evaluates expressions, it converts operands to compatible types (see [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html)).

`'6rubbish'` (a string) gets converted to `6` (a number) and, hence, you get a match.